# Is there a way to insert '-' between the spaces of a string in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example, I have this list:

```
['I am the ', 'ugliest person']
```

I would like to make this list like:

```
['I-am-the ', 'ugliest-person']
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace all occurrences of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string)

Comment: @AnnZen It does not. The blank after "the" is not replaced. Also that's a javascript question.

Comment: Replace ' ' with - . I think I did something similar earlier today but I'm in my bed & too tired too get up and look.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
lst = ['I am the ', 'ugliest person']
lst = ['-'.join(val.split()) for val in lst]
```

`val.split()` will split `val` on any whitespace, and then we rejoin all the split elements with `-`.

To preserve any spaces on the edge of each element of `lst`, you can add these functions:

```
def get_ending_spaces(val):
    return ' ' * (len(val) - len(val.rstrip()))

def get_beginning_spaces(val):
    return ' ' * (len(val) - len(val.lstrip()))
```

and change the list comprehension to

```
lst = [get_beginning_spaces(val) + '-'.join(val.split()) + get_ending_spaces(val) for val in lst]
```

If all your usecases are like your example (where there's no left whitespace), then feel free to remove the `get_beginning_spaces` call.

Output for

```
[' I am the ', ' ugliest person ']
```

ends up being

```
[' I-am-the ', ' ugliest-person ']
```

Comment: What about leading whitespace? :)

Comment: @timgeb that's enough whitespace for the day : P

Answer (score 2):

you can try the below list comprehension

```
new_list = [x.replace(' ','-') for x in list]
```

This will create a  new list named 'new_list' with the spaces replaced with dashes (-)
Hope this helps

Edit: The above code does not preserve the trailing spaces as commented by OP. The below change will probably fix it (only if a single trailing space is involved :/)

```
new_list = [x[:-1].replace(' ','-') if x[-1]==' ' else x.replace(' ','-') for x in list]
```

So a proper solution will be more like this:

```
def replace_spaces(sentence):
    l = sentence.split(' ')
    l = [x if x for x in l]
    return '-'.join(l)
new_list = [ replace_spaces(x) for x in list]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [re](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjwjMrK5u3pAhVNnOAKHeoXBtAQFjAAegQIAxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.python.org%2F3%2Flibrary%2Fre.html&usg=AOvVaw3Rsq9kABRxR4gH08n-cRdW) to do this:

```
import re

l = ['I am the ', 'ugliest person']
for i,s in enumerate(l):
    for n in re.findall('\w *?\w',s): # Finds all spaces that are between 2 letters
        s = s.replace(n,n.replace(' ','-')) # Only replace the spaces that are between 2 letters
    l[i] = s

print(l)
```

Output:

```
['I-am-the ', 'ugliest-person']
```

Answer (score -1):

```
List = ['test test test ', 'test y jk ']
lenght = len(List)
i = 0
while i < lenght:
   List[i] = List[i].replace(' ', '-')
   i += 1
print(List)
```

Comment: `val.replace('-')` does nothing to the original string, so this code have no effect.

Comment: you've made in erreor, it is replace(' ', '-'), that means re replace space ' ' with '-'

Comment: My point is that the strings are not changed, run the code and see.

Comment: you are right, i edited my answer. and i tried it, it works fine

Comment: please explain why do you find it not useful